# how to update an element of an array in Mongodb using mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5ac94112d99fefa76215853a"),
     "id" : "4969c4b2-afbf-4fba-bbb3-95a6899b446d", 
    "profiles" : [ { "loginInfo" : { "providerID" : "credentials",
     "providerKey" : "mc1@mc.com" }, "confirmed" : false,
     "email" : "mc1@mc.com", "firstName" : "m1", 
    "lastName" : "c1", "fullName" : "m1 c1", 
    "passwordInfo" : { "hasher" : "bcrypt", 
"password" : "$2a$10$5F62Gza9Z1ic7OabtXAQEeZhPqm7dfQfjlMMReI64cSZ8q0LJ3HQa" } } ]}
```

I want to change the value of the field `confirmed` from `false` to `true` using `mongo` shell. I tried the following command but it failed. What am I doing wrong?

> db.users.update( {id:"4969c4b2-afbf-4fba-bbb3-95a6899b446d"}, {$set: {'profiles.confirmed' : true}});

Error

```
WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 16837,
                "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (profiles of profiles.confirmed) to traverse the element ({profiles: [ { loginInfo: { providerID: \"credentials\", providerKey: \"mc1@mc.com\" }, confirmed: false, email: \"mc1@mc.com\", firstName: \"m1\", lastName: \"c1\", fullName: \"m1 c1\", passwordInfo: { hasher: \"bcrypt\", password: \"$2a$10$5F62Gza9Z1ic7OabtXAQEeZhPqm7dfQfjlMMReI64cSZ8q0LJ3HQa\" } } ]})"
        }
})
>
```

Comment: Use `profiles.$[].confirmed` to update all profiles, or a specific index otherwise - you are also traversing an array between these two subdocuments. Keep in mind it might not work on older mongo servers.

Comment: tried ` db.users.update( {id:"4969c4b2-afbf-4fba-bbb3-95a6899b446d"}, {$set: {'profiles.$[].confirmed' : true}});`. It didn't work. I am using version 3.6.2

Comment: Interesting, it's actually a fix to 3.5.x: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243 although I'm a bit tired and might have missed something

Comment: tomorrow morning then :) Good night!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.users.update({
    id: "4969c4b2-afbf-4fba-bbb3-95a6899b446d",
    "profiles": {
        $elemMatch: {
            confirmed: false
        }
    }
}, {
    $set: {
        'profiles.$.confirmed': true
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I do agree with Maximilian that it would be helpful if you could explain what I was doing wrong and how your solution works.

Comment: Thanks @ManuChadha to accept myt answer .Into above update query we have used $elemMatch operator to filter values into an array